# Can't test for folder with hashtag in the name

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, escaping

I'm trying to check for folder existence with this code:

```
if [ -d "/MYFOLDERS/#2569/" ] ; then echo "exists" ; fi
```

The folder is there but the script doesn't work...

I believe the problem is with the "#" character as when i test for a different folder without this character everything works fine.

Comment: What is the OS? If you do ls -l /MYFOLDERS/#2569/, what do you see?

Comment: Try single quotes instead of double quotes: `if [ -d '/MYFOLDERS/#2569/' ] ; then echo "exists" ; fi`

Comment: OS X
Single quotes doesn't work.

Comment: "ls -l /MYFOLDERS/#2569/" returns "no such file or directory"

Comment: Probably MYFOLDERS does not exist under root '/'. Try relative path

Comment: "ls -l /MYFOLDERS/" returns a proper list of subfolders so it does exist

Comment: So when you do ls, is  '#2569' one of the sub-folders returned? what is the result of 
"ls -l /MYFOLDERS/#2569' without a '/' at the end?

Comment: "ls -l /MYFOLDERS/#2569" returns "no such file or directory" but "ls -l /MYFOLDERS" returns a proper list and the "#2569" one is included in both

Answer (score 1):

I tested this on MacOSX and I managed to get the condition working:

I created a directory `mkdir \#abc` and then ran the following shell script that returned "exists".

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -d '#abc' ] ; then echo "exists" ; fi
```

Comment: yes, this works. seems like the problem is not in the script but in the directory? i don't know why does it work in home directory and doesn't in root...

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not in the code but in the name of the folder.

Somehow i had a folder named "#2569 " with a space at the end.

Changed the name to "#2569" and it works nicely ;)

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for help!